# How can I add padding to an element on my page?

Tags: css, wordpress, margin, padding

I am working out of wordpress. I have tried using inspect element to move a line of text that is basically overlapping another line of text in the ecwid plugin.

It does not seem to work, every time I edit the css code by using margins or padding attributes nothing happens

On my page where it says $205 for the product , was $295 is touching it and I want to separate that from the actual price.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried using this code

```
html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body div.ecwid-productBrowser-price-compareTo-container{
 padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

here is a look at exactly what im reffering to

https://surveillanceshack.com/store/#!/Elec-Surveillance-system-w-4-bullet-&-4-dome/p/55396210/category=0

Comment: can someone please go to the checkout page ....its worse on that page ...every single line of text is overlapping ...... you can just enter in any type of information to proceed to the page im referring to .... its the page were ppl would inter in there credit card info ..... thats my BIIGEST PROBLEM ...iv been stresssed all day over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line height like this:

```
html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body div.ecwid-productBrowser-price {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #a20505;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

Both of your prices are included inside the same div. When you have text that wraps, the only way to separate them is to define a height between the lines.

To fix your checkout problem fix the line-height there as well on this class:

```
.hentry table, #comments table {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

If you want to fix this problem in one single CSS set of instructions do this instead:

```
.hentry table, #comments table, .ecwid-productBrowser-price {
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

Comment: ok cause I am having the same problem on my checkout page man...and thanks for helping me ... on my check out page where people would enter there credit card info ..... every single line of text is overlapping on another.... would this fix that problem as well?

Comment: @chris - Sounds like you should adjust your *base* line-height for the site.  This is likely causing all of these issues.  I see it's 1.3em - that's pretty short.  You'd likely want it to be a bit taller (not pixels, but em), like 1.5 or 1.6em

Comment: Not likely, if you look at the instructions you are telling it to do it only when the HTML is following the same path as it shows in this CSS rule. Best way is to find a common class you can attach whenver you need this, or find a common scope

Comment: @cale_b is right. Line -height is definitily your problem, not padding, but before you overwrite anything, adjust the values you already have. This of course can still lead into the question, Why was it defined so low by the template designers? Could this line-height be necessary in most places except those two you are having problems with?

Comment: It's a give and take. If adjusting the initial value fixes most of your problems, do that. If not, Find a specicifty that works for both of your only problems

Comment: @cale_b   did you see the comment I put above about the second problem I am having. It is a major issue. Please look into it,  you have fixed the first issue can you please go to my checkout page it is a disaster

Comment: @chris I edited my answer to fix your problem on your checkout page

Comment: did you see what I was talking about ...it was the page that has the credit card input fields on it

Comment: u did it dude ....my main issue i needed fixed ...thanks man...you earned the best answer today over all for sticking with me ...! thanks again man!!

Comment: lol. well, glad I helped, You should upvote @cale_b answer too. His answer was also pretty solid. Worth some rep points ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that it is a span element, which does not really accept margin / padding well.

The element in question is this:

```
html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body .ecwid span
```

So, to make it have space above it, you can add this style to the stylesheet (at the end):

```
html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body .ecwid span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Adjust the `padding-top` to suite your desired layout.

Alternatively, you could do this by increasing the `line-height` of the element (in which case it does not need to be `display: inline-block`):

```
html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body .ecwid span {
    line-height: 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: aye man the second code you gave me worked ..... would it work the  other issue i have up above?

Comment: Please look at the comment I have placed above , it is the main problem .... I tried adding a span to the code but it didnt work ... like I said you have fixed the first issue I was having.... so please look into the other.... I will award you the best answer either way ...

Answer (score 0):

It is a span element, to make padding active, you need to add :

```
{
display :inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding for "was" element.

`html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body div.ecwid-productBrowser-price-compareTo-container, html#ecwid_html body#ecwid_body div.ecwid-productBrowser-price-save-container {
    padding-bottom:5px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

(Ecwid team here)

While the answers here can help to fix the issues yourself, we will investigate how Ecwid works with your "DMS" theme and make sure to fix those on our side. The issue is already in our devs queue, we will roll out the solution in one of the Ecwid plugin updates in the near future.